# Что такое артефакт в TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity

Не совсем понимаю для чего нужны артефакты в TeamCity. Объясните, пожалуйста, простыми словами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Артефакт сборки - это то, ради чего сборка производилась - набор выходных файлов, пригодных для скачивания или использования в других сборках.

Comment: Например, бинарники?

Comment: @Марк да, например они самые

Comment: А как их использовать?

Comment: @Марк прочитайте про [artifact dependencies](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Artifact+Dependencies).